# Possible to write $\{ f_{k} \to f\ \text{uniformly} \}$?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, notation, quantifiers

Because of the quantifier position thing, I doubt it is possible to write $\{ f_{k} \to f\ \text{uniformly} \}$. If it is possible, how so? If not, how so?

This question is out of this: I used to write "$f_{k} \to f$ uniformly on E", say; in an attempt to write it as "$\{ f_{k} \to f\ \text{uniformly} \} \supset E$", I came across this problem.

On the other hand, we can write "$\{ f_{k} \to f\ \text{pointwisely} \} \supset E$" to express "$f_{k} \to f$ pointwisely on $E$"; for
$$
\{ f_{k} \to f\ \text{pointwisely} \} = \cap_{m}\cup_{N}\cap_{k \geq N} \{ |f_{k} - f| < 1/m \}.
$$

Comment: If you allow me to consider only functions whose domain is exactly $E$ and the codomain is $\mathbb R$, then it would be $$\left\{a\in \left(\mathbb R^{E}\right)^{\mathbb N}\colon \mathop{\exists}_{f\in \mathbb R^{E}}\mathop{\forall}_{\varepsilon >0}\mathop{\exists}_{p\in \mathbb N}\mathop{\forall}_{  n \in \mathbb N}\mathop{\forall}_{  x \in E}\left(n\ge p\implies \left|a_n(x)-f(x)\right|<\varepsilon\right)\right\}_.$$ If you don't allow me this, then it gets a little more complicated, but you get the idea.

Comment: For better readability: $$\left\{a\in \left(\mathbb R^{E}\right)^{\mathbb N}\colon \mathop{\large \exists}_{\large f\in \mathbb R^{E}}\mathop{\large \forall}_{\large \varepsilon >0}\mathop{\large \exists}_{\large p\in \mathbb N}\mathop{\large \forall}_{ \large  n \in \mathbb N}\mathop{\large \forall}_{\large   x \in E}\left(n\ge p\implies \left|a_n(x)-f(x)\right|<\varepsilon\right)\right\}_.$$

Comment: If I understood what you're trying to do, the fact is that "the set where the sequence $f_k$ converges uniformly to $f$" is often not definable in a sensible way. More precisely, the set $$\mathcal U=\{A\subseteq \Bbb R\,:\, f_k\to f\text{ uniformly on }A\}$$ ordered by inclusion "$\subseteq$", often does not have maximal elements. For instance, for the Taylor series of $e^x$ it does not.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I think you do! If you got an idea making my question clearer (to me it is clear enough, but I am not a native English speaker), please feel free to do so.